# ConcurrentModificationException with ORMlite on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, ormlite, concurrentmodification

I'm having tons of `ConcurrentModificationException` when doing some update operations with my database using ORMlite. I'm wrapping the code that does the actual update into `rx.Observables` to make it asynchronously. Looks like this:

```
@Override
public void setFavoriteTeams(List<Team> teams) {
    final Iterator<Team> it = teams.iterator();
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {

            try {
                List<String> teamIds = new ArrayList<>();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Team team = it.next();
                    teamIds.add(team.getmSipId());
                }

                setFavoriteTeamsSql(teamIds);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handleException(e);
            } finally {
                subscriber.onNext(null);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe();
}
```

Ironically, a while ago I started using `Interator` instead of a for-loop to avoid any `ConcurrenceModificationException` that may happen, but instead they increased a lot. The `setFavoriteTeamsSql(List<String>)` method simply uses ORMlite's UpdateBuilder class to update the table. The exception is being thrown at the `Team team = it.next();` line.

Any idea about how to fix this? Right now I'm rolling back the changes and going back to the for-loop. But I'd like doing this the right way.

**UPDATE:**

This is how the Stacktrace looks like:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
       at com.siplay.android_siplay.data.cache.db.DBTeamCache$4.call(DBTeamCache.java:164)
       at com.siplay.android_siplay.data.cache.db.DBTeamCache$4.call(DBTeamCache.java:157)
       at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10150)
       at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:172)
       at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
...
mNetworkTeamRepository
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .obseveOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<List<Teams>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Team> teams) {
            mTeamsCache.setFavoriteTeams(teams);
        }

        public void onResult(List<Team> teams) {
            callback.showTeams(teams);
        }
    });
...
```

The TeamRepository internally uses a Retrofit service to get the server-side response.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to

```
public void setFavoriteTeams(List<Team> teams) {
  Observable
  .fromIterable(teams)
  .map(Team::getmSipId)
  .toList()
  .doOnNext(this::setFavoriteTeamsSql)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .subscribe();
}
```

But I still can't see how your code emits `ConcurrentModificationException` - maybe a stack trace will help?

Comment: I updated my question with the Stacktrace. Yeah the first thing that I'm gonna try is to move the Iterator down into the Subscriber.

Comment: Also, important - does any other part of your code modify the passed-in list? Because it doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: Well, yeah, what happens is that in a server-side request response I get a list of teams, then I call this method to save the response in the database, and then I pass the collection through a callback into the UI. The request is being sent from several screens so I'm not sure which can be failing. But the Interactor in the setFavoriteTeams shouldn't prevent that?

Comment: I'm gonna update the answer with my Interactor/UseCase implementation so you can see what I'm talking about

Comment: Maybe just do a copy: `final Iterator<Team> it = new ArrayList<>(teams).iterator();`

Comment: Ok, I thought that using `Iterator` was a definitive solution to the `ConcurrentModificationException` problems. I'm gonna see if doing that copy works.

Comment: Ok, both things worked. Moving the iterator inside the OnSubcribe class or copying the collection as you said. Please update your answer so I can mark it as approved. BTW this issues only happened in Android 6 devices. So if anyone runs into the same weird issue, please check agains an Android 6 emulator.